# How to call a service with a char argument

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you pass a char to `rosservice call`?

I have a srv file like:

```
uint8 id
string data
---
```

exposed as `/myservice` which I'd like to call like `rosservice call /myservice m '!!str mydata'` but this gives me a Python traceback to the autogenerated code for my srv class:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_x' referenced before assignment
```

presumably because it doesn't convert "m" to the uint8 value 109. The [docs declare](http://wiki.ros.org/msg) char is deprecated because it's essentially the same thing as uint8.

Is there a way to explicitly declare this type, or do I have to pass in a literal int value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228943/how-to-call-a-service-with-a-char-argument/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not familiar with the way you call the service.
I usually do it this way

> rosservice call /myservice '{id: A,
> data: ok}'

---

Originally posted by [Arowana](https://answers.ros.org/users/22294/arowana/) with karma: 381 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-03-13**:
I tried that hash notation, but that gives me the error, "expected [id, data]. I guess it assumes a list notation for custom services?